# Flutter run on multiple physical devices simultaneously

Tags: android, flutter, adb

`flutter run -d <deviceId>` allows running the app on a specific device.

Emulators have device id as `emulator-5554`, `emulator-5556` and so on. Thus I can specify the emulator to use, using `flutter run -d emulator-5554`

When I connect two physical devices, a phone, and a tablet and run `adb devices -l` I get
the same device id for both devices. Thus, Flutter cannot run on both devices simultaneously.

[image: deviceIds]

As you can see one is a phone LS 5020 and the other is a tablet P702 but the device id is the same.
The same is found on both Windows 10 and Linux Mint 19.2

---

Is there a way to fix this using any other command to specify the device to use or somehow change the device id?

**EDIT:**
output of `flutter devices`
flutter devices

> 1 connected device:
>
> 0123456789ABCDEF • 0123456789ABCDEF • android-arm64 • Android 6.0 (API 23)

Also, `flutter run -d all` runs the app on one of these devices

Output of  `flutter devices -v`

```
[  +44 ms] executing: /home/droid/androidSdkUbuntu/platform-tools/adb devices -l
[  +13 ms] Exit code 0 from: /home/droid/androidSdkUbuntu/platform-tools/adb devices -l
[        ] List of devices attached
           0123456789ABCDEF       no permissions (user in plugdev group; are your udev rules wrong?); see [http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html] usb:1-3 transport_id:16
           0123456789ABCDEF       device usb:3-2 product:LS-5020 model:LS_5020 device:LS-5020 transport_id:12
[  +22 ms] 1 connected device:

[   +3 ms] /home/droid/androidSdkUbuntu/platform-tools/adb -s 0123456789ABCDEF shell getprop
[  +70 ms] ro.hardware = mt6735
[        ] ro.build.characteristics = default
[   +3 ms] 0123456789ABCDEF • 0123456789ABCDEF • android-arm64 • Android 6.0 (API 23)
```

Comment: does `flutter devices` show the same?

Comment: Posted the output.

Comment: `-h` gives nothing except info about command. `adb` is default provided by android studio

Comment: `adb --version` gives
`Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
Version 29.0.5-5949299`

Comment: `flutter devices -h`
`List all connected devices.

Usage: flutter devices [arguments]
-h, --help    Print this usage information.

Run "flutter help" to see global options.`

Comment: sorry i mean `flutter devices -v`, not `-h` - it will show the full `adb` command

Comment: check edit in answer

Comment: check last 12 lines - sterting from: `/home/droid/androidSdkUbuntu/platform-tools/adb devices -l [ ]`

Comment: posted in the question edit

Comment: I have run the command `flutter devices -v` in some cases and the final result is posted with both devices connected.

When both devices are connected `flutter run -d all` runs only on phone in all cases. When devices are used separately both work fine on their own.

Looks like flutter is running the command on the first device and the phone is always listed first. Also, it says only one device is connected due to the same device id.
Can I change the device id?
Or use any other parameter like  `device usb`,`product`, `model`, `device` or `transport_id` as they are different for both?

Comment: did you notice: `0123456789ABCDEF       no permissions (user in plugdev group; are your udev rules wrong?); see [http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html] usb:1-3 transport_id:16` ? tried to fix that?

Comment: Yes, I have checked that. If USB tethering is OFF for the tablet then the issue is not shown. But the app does not run without tethering set to ON. So, even though it shows error it runs fine.

Answer (score 2):

Give `flutter run -d all` a try.

Comment: I was hoping to run via Android Studio config rather than command-line version but will check this.

Comment: tested; runs only on 1 device and not both.

Comment: That's weird. To be clear, the apps are built and launched one after another, not at the same time. You can also use their names (P702 & LS-5020) but I don't think you can include multiple devices in one command. By the way, you can 
[create a configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54532722/3925977) for that command.

Comment: can you give me an example of a command to run using their name? I run using the command `flutter run -d <deviceID>` which is the main issue here.

Comment: Device id and name are interchangeable here. So it would be `flutter run -d P702` and `flutter run -d LS-5020`

Comment: Running with name works for tablet separately; not working for the phone in any case(using only device id works). When both are connected and config is run for the tablet using its name, it fails as it uses `deviceId` under the hood for the command. It looks like using the name of the device is provided as a handy shortcut for not typing the deviceId.

Answer (score 0):

Open your terminal and type `flutter run` it will ask you to pick the device you want to use and do that by simply picking the numbered device of choice