# How to hot reload on both ios and android devices at the same time using IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: flutter, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA to code Flutter and usually have 2 simulators running (ios and android). It is kinda annoying when I have to switch the target device manually when I update the code.

Any plugin that can do the trick for IntelliJ IDEA

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter Hot Reload to multiple devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51669258/flutter-hot-reload-to-multiple-devices)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

~As I know, this feature only supported in Visual Studio Code~

Please check https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Multi-device-debugging-in-VS-Code

**Updated Genchi Genbutsu**

It possible to do with console commands
[Flutter Hot Reload to multiple devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51669258/flutter-hot-reload-to-multiple-devices/51855251)

Comment: Yeah, I think this is what we got =))

Comment: @GenchiGenbutsu update answer, thx, don;t even know about posibility with console commands