# How do I deploy release version with flutter to only physical devices?

Tags: ios, flutter

I would like to deploy a flutter app to all *physical* phones connected. My current solution is to deploy to each device one at a time, but I would like to do them all at once. The closest match I found from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51855251/7228140) is to use `flutter run -d all` with the `--release` flag in order to deploy to all devices.

However, using `-d all` attempts to deploy to emulators as well, which throws this error (and does not deploy to any of the devices):

```
Release mode is not supported by iPhone 8.
```

Output of `flutter devices` looks like this (with true ids removed):

```
PhysicalPixel (mobile)   • XXX1    • android-arm64  • Android 11 (API 30)
PhysicaliPhone (mobile)  • XXX2    • ios            • iOS 14.4.1
iPhone 8 (mobile)        • XXX3    • ios            • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-14-5 (simulator)
Chrome (web)             • chrome  • web-javascript • Google Chrome
```

Is there a way to "deploy all" only to physical devices? Desired result deploys to `PhysicalPixel` and `PhysicaliPhone` (etc. with more phones), but not to `iPhone 8` (simulator) or `Chrome`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it isn't possible to order a to run on only physical devices by some form of argument, but you can specify which devices instead of `-d all`

If you combine the this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/59593575/13263384) from the same question you linked to, together wit a small alteration to the launch.json then it might be what you are after. So do something like this:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Physical-1",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart",
            "deviceId": "XXX1",
            "args": [
                "--release"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Physical-2",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart",
            "deviceId": "XXX2",
            "args": [
                "--release"
            ]
        },
        "compounds": [
        {
            "name": "Physical devices",
            "configurations": [
                "Physical-1",
                "Physical-2"

            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The compound name *Physical devices* will now be a runnable target which will launch the build to those devices.

**Edit:**
Now that I read that answer more thouroughly, I think that answer is actually better than mine. But up to you how you want to do it!

Comment: Does something like this work _without_ using VScode? I'm not using VScode -- just deploying from a terminal.

Comment: Ah okey. No, not that I'm aware of. In that case I'd try writing a simple start-script that does the manual labor of launching against one device at a time using -d. (I guess basically what VSCode does in the background)